# Finding the hypotenuse on a triangle with a circle inscribed.

Tags: triangles, circles, problem-solving

[image: Circle of radius r inscribed in obtuse triangle]

The problem is a right-angled triangle with a inscribed circle, see figure, where you want to solve the distance CB (the hypotenuse).

The only known values are two lines which are linked to the circle center and the the corners of the hypotenuse.

I have tried many different methods but can't seem to solve it. I was told the solution would be simpler than I thought.

Note: You are only allowed to solve the problem though Euclidean means.

Comment: HINT. Distances from $B$ and $C$ to tangency points are $\sqrt{9-r^2}$ and $\sqrt{4-r^2}$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, i have gotten that far but all of my attempts to continue are to no avail. I just cant seem to get to a solution which will not mean using any hardcore caluculations. (perhaps there is no easy solution but i was told there was :/ )

Comment: Let $I$ be the incentre, then $\angle CIB = 135^\circ$. If you know how to derive the cosine rule through Euclidean means, then maybe you would be able to prove that $$CB^2 = 2^2 + 3^2 - 2\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cos 135^\circ$$ without mentioning the word "cosine".

Comment: How is  $\angle CIB = 135^{\circ }$?Assuming r=1 then the angle parts add up 60+75 degrees however $\cos 75 \ne 1/3. $

Comment: @Narasimham $\triangle ABC$ is given to be a right-angled triangle, and $r$ has a fixed value.

Comment: @Narasimham If you let the circle's tangent point on $AC$ be $D$, that on $AB$ be $E$ and that on $BC$ be $F$, then $\angle ICD=\angle ICF=\alpha$ and $\angle IBE=\angle IBF=\beta$. Also, $\angle CID=90^{\circ}-\alpha$, $\angle BIE=90^{\circ}-\beta$, so $\angle CIB=360^{\circ}-(90^{\circ}-\alpha)-90^{\circ}-(90^{\circ}-\beta)=90^{\circ}+\alpha+\beta$. However, $2\alpha+2\beta=90^{\circ}$, so $\angle CIB=90^{\circ}+45^{\circ}=135^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pythagoras theorem by writing all the sides only in terms of r.

$AC^2+AB^2=BC^2$

$(r+\sqrt{2^2-r^2})^2+(r+\sqrt{3^2-r^2})^2 = (\sqrt{3^2-r^2}+\sqrt{2^2-r^2})^2$

Then find r from this equation and hence find CB.

Comment: is this really the correct way? there must be some additional steps the simplify this. I have tried doing this earlier but its way to hard to get a solution for "r" from this.

Comment: @ImLazor Yes, this method is correct, though lengthy. If you want a shorter solution, you could use the cosine rule, which would give you the same answer for CB in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

We let $\,h\,$ be the hypotenuse, let $\,x\,$ be the part of the hypotenuse near the $\,C\,$ vertex, and let $\,r\,$ be the inradius.

\begin{align*}
x&=\sqrt{2^2-r^2}\\
h-x&=\sqrt{3^2-r^2}\\
\implies x&=h-\sqrt{3^2-r^2}\\\\
x=\sqrt{2^2-r^2}&=h-\sqrt{3^2-r^2}\\
\implies h&=\sqrt{2^2-r^2}+\sqrt{3^2-r^2}
\end{align*}